# Some apps block Screen Mirroring. How to unblock that?

Tags: video-recording, chromecast, screencast, editing, miracast

Some apps block Screen Mirroring. This means that application developers can choose themselves if they want to block Screen Mirroring.

An example is "JioTV" app.
Many Modders are able to **allow** screen mirroring in its mod versions.

Such apps **does not allow screen recording** also. When casting or screen recording, they display black screen and block audio in the recording.

I want to **mod** "**MS Teams**" **apk** so I can screen record the class in my android phone without creating a public notification.

Any idea where to look for the "screen cast/record" code line!, That I can edit so I can finally screen record the app? I use Apk-Editor to edit apps.

Till now I have to use screen record in my pc to achieve this because Ms Teams android app blocks it. But I want to record in phone because it is more easily portable.

Comment: If you have a PC you can connect your phone and record everything using [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy). No need for modding anything.

Comment: Thank you So Much ! Scrcpy is just what I needed. My problem is solved.